# Breadth First search query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, breadth-first-search

Here's a table in tree structure.

```
id  parent_id
1   0
2   1
3   8
4   8
5   1
6   8
7   6
8   1
9   2
10  6
```

And I need to retrieve data by "Breadth First".

So the order should be : 1 → (8 → 5 → 2) → (6 → 4 → 3) → 9 → (10 → 7)

Actually there's a another column to sort same depth of nodes.`8,5,2`, `6,4,3`, `10,7`.
I exclude it to simplify this case. So the sequence of same depth node : `8,5,2`, `5,8,2` `2,5,8`... is okay.

[image]

Comment: //hims056  It's about the navigation(menu). The problem is that the order of data retrieved from MYSQL and the order of HTML element is different. I'm trying to order data same as HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadth-first search order is just `ORDER BY depth_column_that_you_thought_is_irrelevant ASC`, if you don't care about the order of nodes within a layer (which you probably don't need in most uses of BFS). If you do care about having people with the same parent go together, then `ORDER BY depth, parent_id`. You don't give any explicit precedence of sister nodes, so can't help you there.

Also, your graph does not match your data, or I could not figure out how `id: 3, parent_id: 2` row translates to either 3 <- 8, or 9 <- 2 in the graph.

Comment: I made a mistake while making the data random(like actual data). I change the table.